# Add an unsafe header in a content-script for a single request

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

In a browser extension I'm creating I need to process an ajax request made in a content-script.

Although the url has the same host that the page we're into, it turns out I **need to add some unsafe headers** (`Sec-Fetch-Mode`, `Sec-Fetch-Dest`, ...), because the server (an OpenProject private copy) will respond with a `410 Gone` without them.

These headers can't be placed by jQuery's AJAX (`Refuse to set unsafe header`), but as **I am in a content-script**, and thus in a browser extension, I should be able to bypass (somehow) this security barrier (obviously with extra permissions).

So, the question is: **how can I make an AJAX request with unsafe headers in a browser extension?**

Bonus points if it's compatible with both Manifest V2 and V3 :)

Comment: These headers should be set automatically when you make the request from the correct place i.e. an image element. Anyway, extensions can set these headers via chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders (MV2) or chrome.declarativeNetRequest (MV3, not tested) and make the request in the background script.

Comment: In my particular case, `Sec-Fetch-Dest` is `empty`, and loading the same page in a tab instead of ajax sets this header to `document`. I've seen that some servers reject these requests to prevent script injection. That's why I should change it. I will try onBeforeSendHeaders, thanks for the advice! (Though there might be a single-host listener but it turns out not...)